# Missing control sequence inserted ressubheading

Tags: errors, cv

First-time LaTeX user here!

I'm using Overleaf (used to be WriteLatex) and when trying to use one of their CV templates, I get an error without event typing a single letter in the code.

Template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/aparna-cv/ckldkvjcjwxz#.VTLIhPnF98E

Error:

```
Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.84 ...ty}{Fargo, ND}{B.Sc. Physics}{2004 - 2008}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that we like questions here to be self-contained so they stay useful even if Overleaf modify their templates!

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is earlier. If you replace the line, where IIT Madras Logo is called (line 68 of the original template), e.g. as in the example, everything works OK. (You don't have  this logo, I suppose.)

```
% (c) 2002 Matthew Boedicker <mboedick@mboedick.org> (original author) http://mboedick.org
% (c) 2003-2007 David J. Grant <davidgrant-at-gmail.com> http://www.davidgrant.ca
% (c) 2008 Nathaniel Johnston <nathaniel@nathanieljohnston.com> http://www.nathanieljohnston.com
% (l) 2012 Arun I B <arunib@smail.iitm.ac.in> http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~ee10s026/
%This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 2.5 License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/ or send a letter to Creative Commons, 543 Howard Street, 5th Floor, San Francisco, California, 94105, USA.

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Aparna-CV}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Insert IIT Madras Logo 
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%  & \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.19]{iitmlogo}}\\ % HERE!
 & \multirow{4}{*}{}\\
  & \\
%-----------------------------------------------------------  
  \textbf{\Large Sreekanth $|$ EE10S0600 } & \\
  Research Scholar & \\
  IIT Madras, Chennai, India  \\
  ajacob@smail.iitm.ac.in \\
\end{tabular*}
\\


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Education}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{My University}{My Town, ON}{B.Sc. Physics}{2004 - 2008}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{Undergraduate Thesis: Why Electron Spins Rule}
        \resitem{Graduated with Honours and a XX.X\% average}
    \end{itemize}

\item
    \ressubheading{My High School}{Hick Town, ON}{High School Diploma}{2000 - 2004}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{President of Students' Council and captain of the rugby team in senior year}
        \resitem{Graduated with a XX.X\% average}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Personal Statement}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{center}
  \parbox{6.762in}{I'm the hardest working person I know, and therefore you should hire me. My qualities include blah, blah, and blah. I have lots of experience working with blah, and I am not afraid to blah. In fact, I'm such an amazing person that I can't believe you haven't hired me yet.}
  \end{center}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Work Experience}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{Calculus I}{My University}{Undergraduate Teaching Assistant}{Sept. 2007 - Apr. 2008}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{Graded assignments.}
        \resitem{Led weekly course seminars.}
    \end{itemize}

\item 
    \ressubheading{Happy Time Farms}{Hick Town, ON}{Farm Hand}{Sept. 2000 - Dec. 2002}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{Milked cows.}
        \resitem{Milked goats.}
        \resitem{Milked cats.}
    \end{itemize}

\item
    \ressubheading{Hick Town Press}{Hick Town, ON}{Paperboy}{June 1996 - Aug. 2000}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{Delivered the local newspaper to 70 customers every morning.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Awards, Grants \& Honours}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \vspace{-2pt}
    \begin{center}\begin{tabular*}{6.6in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Physics Graduation Prize (\$XXX) \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}2007}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Award of Awesomeness (\$XXX) \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} 2006}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{My University Entrance Scholarship (\$X XXX) \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}2004}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{My High School Grade 12 Physics Award (\$XXX) \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}2004}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Boy Genius Award (\$XXX) \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}2003}\\
        \vphantom{E}
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}\vspace*{-16pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Skills}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item
    Programming and Markup Languages
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{{\bf Expert:} CSS, HTML}
        \resitem{{\bf Intermediate:} Java, \LaTeX, Python}
    \end{itemize}

\item
    Software
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{{\bf Expert:} MS Access, MS Excel, MS Word}
        \resitem{{\bf Intermediate:} Maple, MATLAB}
    \end{itemize}


\item
    Other
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{People person, enjoys being challenged, hardworking, smells nice}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the code, I could get through the compilation by commenting

```
\ressubheading{My High School}{Hick Town, ON}{High School Diploma}{2000 - 2004}
```

for which the entry part code was

```
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}
{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
```

Apparently the code isn't written clearly but from what I understand they are trying to write the subheading using tabular like one in the manual([Wiki Latex Tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)).

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{.}l}
  3   & 14159 \\
  16  & 2     \\
  123 & 456   \\
\end{tabular}
```

So the solution would be to change the definition of resubheading to following

```
\begin{tabular}
{l@{\hspace{120mm}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular}\vspace{-6pt}}
```

The above code is a hack. You can change the logic to fit everything more neatly.

Comment: This will break various custom configuration code/commands.